# How to define a type for a module inside the module itself?

Tags: typescript, types, module

Say I have a typescript file, named `hello-service.ts`:

```
export function hello1() { ... }
export function hello2() { ... }
export function hello3() { ... }
```

In some cases, we want the type of this module. We can refer it in another ts file like this:

```
import * as helloService from './hello-service.ts';

function getHelloModule(): typeof helloService {
  return hello;
}
```

But I want to know, if is it possible to define such a type **inside** the `hello-service.ts` file itself?

For now, I can only achieve this by specifying every function, and which is quite boring:

```
export type HelloServiceType = {
   hello1: typeof hello1,
   hello2: typeof hello2,
   hello3: typeof hello3
}
```

Is there any simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the type of an import as `typeof import('./hello-service.ts')`. This will for sure work from outside the module. I have never used it from within a module, but from what I tried it works as expected even if it is a bit recursive:

```
// ./hello-service.ts
export function hello1() {  }
export function hello2() {  }
export function hello3() {  }


declare var exports: Self;
type Self = typeof import('./hello-service') 
export let self: Self = exports;

// usage.ts

import * as hello from './hello-service'
hello.self.hello1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Titian's answer can be further simplified:

**`hello.ts`**

```
export function hello1() { return 1 }
export function hello2() { return 1 }
export function hello3() { return 1 }

export type TypeOfThisModule = typeof import ('./hello');
```